# Windows 8.1 repair loop

Tags: windows-8.1, gateway, repair, infinite-loop

I have a gateway with Windows 8.1 and it's stuck in the repair loop I don't have a repair disk and  I don't have admin set up, I've tryed all the options it gives and it's still a no go please help

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a recovery partition set up on the machine since you don't have the Windows DVD? If yes boot into the recovery partition and use the repair tool.

Comment: No it tells me I need to be signed in as a admin wich I didn't know I need to setup